# 3d scan matting spray

Tags: 3d-models

I want to scan a few ceramic items that are shiny and have multiple colors and found that using an artec 3d Spider that doesn't really work due to the shininess and thus want to use a matting spray or sth to be able to get proper results. Ideally sth without color that can be used on the ceramic items and allows to obtain proper texture results for the 3d model too. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many variations of a product generically known as chalk spray. Some of them should be considered permanent or semi-permanent, while the [Montana brand product](https://www.montana-cans.com/en/spray-cans/montana-spray-paint/chalk-400ml-marking-spray/montana-chalk-400ml) explicitly states "temporary" in the description. There is a caveat in that it has to be a non-porous surface to be considered temporary.

The product is primarily directed at outside/sidewalk art which can be washed away or will wear away under normal traffic. As such, it is suited for matting shiny surfaces for scanning purposes. White is the best color for scanning as it will accept light and shadows better than the other choices.

I have a can of white and can attest that it will wash off. Some of the product will wipe off dry but the small crevices require washing, which should be considered when spraying your item.

[image: montana chalk spray]

The product is available at many online outlets and may be found at local art supply retailers.